# react-helmet-async only working for the root directory

Tags: reactjs, react-helmet

I'm trying to use react-helmet-async to set page titles but so far it's only working for the root level component.

index.js

```
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <HelmetProvider>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <App />
      </BrowserRouter>
    </HelmetProvider>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

I'm using the Title component to set the title dynamically.

Title.jsx

```
const Title = ({ title }) => {
  return (
    <Helmet>
      <title>CarHouse - {title}</title>
    </Helmet>
  );
};
```

Home.jsx (helmet works for this component)

```
const Home = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Title title="Home" />
      <div className="mt-20 text-center">
        <h1>Home</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Blog.jsx (helmet does not work for this component

```
const Blogs = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Title title="Blogs" />
      <h1>Blogs</h1>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: How are you rendering `Home` and `Blogs` components? Also, could you try running `<Helmet>` directly in those components rather then using `Title` component? I have experiences similar issue long ago and iirc that fixed the issue. But it has been a while.

Comment: I'm using **Route** to render the **Home** and **Blogs** component (react router v6) and I've tried helmet without the **Title** component but the issue persists.

Comment: Mind posting your router file too? That might be an issue maybe? Worth a shot

Comment: May be you could try swapping the order of BrowserRouter and HelmetProvider